# Find name of a database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to find a particular database by name using the SQL Server Management Studio.

Example: find database with name 'database1' on the current server

Comment: using `mySQL` or what ?

Comment: USING sql server through Microsoft sql server management.

Comment: The title says find _table_, but the text says find _database_... What are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'database1'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current database name use

```
select db_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT name
FROM DBname.sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '%database1%'
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%database1%'
```